# 'ERROR: Expect post' after making an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-console

This form is submitted via AJAX, but there are a couple of bugs preventing that from working. How can I use my Chrome browser's console to fix it? The error is:

> ERROR: Expect post.

```html
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Form is broken');">Submit</button>
<h3>Results:</h3>
<div id='results'></div>
```

```js
var success_callback = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $('#results')[0].innerHTML = data;
}

$('button').click(function() {
  $.ajax('ajax.php', {
    data: {
      submission: JSON.stringify({
        prop: $('text_area').val()
      })
    },
    success: success_callback
  });
});
```

Comment: The error is your server telling you that it expects a POST request to the endpoint, yet you're sending a GET. Add `type: 'POST'` in the AJAX settings.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Thanks, I understand I need to add "type: 'POST'" above data in the code. The question is how do I do this specifically in chrome browser console. Thanks!

Comment: You can't. You need to apply it to the JS for all browsers for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you send a request over the internet you need to define a request method: Post, Get, Put, Delete.  Looking at the docs for jQuery.ajax I see that it has a different opinion on how the ajax function should be populated.

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    success_callback(msg)
  });
```

You should also utilize Promises on asynchronous operations so that your code runs more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, I understand I need to add "type: 'POST'" above data in the code. The question is how do I do this specifically in chrome browser console.

Comment: You can copy and paste the code into the console and it will run it